# Catching error, but not exit the App - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to NodeJS. I'm trying to

- catch a bad case that leads to error
- when I catch it, I want to throw an error in my console
- Prevent further code from executing
- Prevent the app from crashing

---

## #1

> I've tried **`process.exit`**

I got the app to exit which I don't want

```
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

---

## #2

> I also tried on **`process.abort`**

I got the app to crash which I don't want.

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

---

## #3

> I also tried on **`uncaughtException`**

```
if(serviceType == 0 || serviceType == '' || serviceType == null) {
    console.error('\x1b[41m%s\x1b[0m', 'bad service type detected');
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
      console.error(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)));
    });
}
```

I got the console to print BUT the code still kept going which I don't want

---

## #4

> I also tried **`throw new Error`**

```
if(serviceType == 0 || serviceType == '' || serviceType == null) {
    console.error('\x1b[41m%s\x1b[0m', 'bad service type detected');
    throw new Error(serviceType);
}
```

I got the console to print, I got the code to stop, BUT I got the big error in the console

```
2018-05-30T17:45:37.307Z - info: The server is listening on port 3333
bad service type detected
{ mac: '102030405060' }
Error: 1
    at Promise (/Users/john/Sites/app/server/factories/policy-factory.js:23:27)
    at Promise._execute (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:303:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
    at new Promise (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
    at Object.policyFactory.create (/Users/john/Sites/app/server/factories/policy-factory.js:13:16)
    at fortinet.createPolicy (/Users/john/Sites/app/server/controllers/fortinet.js:44:47)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/john/Sites/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
2018-05-30T17:45:46.817Z - error: POST /eventserver/ext/vcpe - 1
2018-05-30T17:45:46.818Z - debug: {"body":{"mac":"102030405060"}}
2018-05-30T17:45:46.818Z - verbose: {"token":""}
```

---

## #5

> I also tried on **`return;`**

```
if(serviceType == 0 || serviceType == '' || serviceType == null) {
    console.error('\x1b[41m%s\x1b[0m', 'bad service type detected');
    return;
}
```

I got the app to not crash and got the code to stop where they are.

BUT the process of my requesting seems to hang for so long.

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but so far this approach seems to achieve a lot of the points that I am trying to do.

---

## Questions

**How would one go about and acheive something like this ?**

---

I'm open to any suggestions at this moment.

Comment: You want to `Prevent code from executing.` but you dont want the `app to exit` ?!

Comment: Yes. that what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: Whats your usecase?! If there is something wrong, continuing normally would make everything worse?!

Comment: IF one request to my app is bad, I want to catch it and ignore it, and will send them back the a useful response info. I don't want my app to crash  when I detect 1 bad request or data.

Comment: To keep your process alive something needs to always be in the event loop. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: **@kyo**, I will suggest you to use **try-catch** error handling blocks or if the node modules provide callbacks on **error** then try to use that.You can check https://github.com/hygull/node-runtime/blob/master/README.md page with links to **js** files which I have written for db connection in node.js and I have used callbacks for error handling.

Comment: @kyo thats what `try` / `catch` is for...

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use #4 extended with try and catch block:

```js
// Used for the snippet only
const serviceType = 0;

try {
  // Some logic

  if(serviceType == 0 || serviceType == '' || serviceType == null) {
      throw new Error('Bad service type detected!');
  }
  
  console.log('This message doesn\'t print the console!');

  // Some more logic
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

This way your program doesn't continue in the try block and you can handle the error any way you like in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Expressjs, You can define error handling middleware as suggested in the Expressjs website. As most used Node framework is express I hope this might help.

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

This will catch the server side errors and sent a message without crashing the app. The official link https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html